# Ajax Put Request on Select_tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, spree

I have a DropDown Menu in my View that has a Callback that is being fired as soon as it detects the change event. I want to pass in the Value thats being select in the DropDown to my Line_items controller via ajax and update a specific record.
Sadly, the $.ajax is still a stranger to me.

So far I have:

```
$.ajax(
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text'
      url: 'orders/:order_id/line_items/:id',
      data:
        "variant_id": selectedData.selectedData.value

      success: ->
        alert ('test')
    )
```

What would be the proper way to do so?

Comment: `$.ajax` is equivalent to `jQuery.ajax` (`$` is an alias for `jQuery`).  So what you need to do is read up on this method in jQuery doc, here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you can pass that value in the data as json object; your function may look like:

```
$('#my_dropdown_id').change(function() {
  var sel_value = $(this).val();
  // here you can do some validation, etc; before fire the ajax call if is necessary
  $.ajax({
     url: 'orders/:order_id/line_items/:id',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {variant_id: sel_value},
     success: function(data) {
       alert('OK!')
     }
  })
});
```

then on your back-end you can get that value form the post params. i.e.  params['variant_id']

I m assuming you will build the URL using the proper values for the ids; i.e.

```
url: 'orders/'+ your_order_id +'/line_items/'+ line_item_id,
```